# JSON to JSON transformation using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

input

```
{
"ances": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "level": "Building",
        "name": " Metro Campus Outdoor"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "level": "Campus",
        "name": " Metro Campus"
    }
]
```

}

expected output:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "Building_id": 1,
      "Building": "my building for Outdoor"
    },
    {
      "Building_id": 2,
      "Campus": "Man Metro Campus"
    }
  ]
}


i want to change the name key with the value of the level tag.
```

Answer (score 0):

Spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ances": {
        "*": {
          "id": "result[&1].Building_id",
          "level": {
            "Building": {
              // if we matched all the way down here
              // then go back up and grab the "name" 
              // and write it's value to Building in
              // the result
              "@(2,name)": "result[&3].Building"
            },
            "Campus": {
              "@(2,name)": "result[&3].Campus"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Updated Spec per comment, where Campus and Building should not be hard coded

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "ances": {
        "*": {
          "id": "result[&1].Building_id",
          "level": {
            "*": {
              // if we matched all the way down here
              // then go back up and grab the "name" 
              // and write it's value to 
              // the result array, using the value of 
              //  level as the key
              "@(2,name)": "result[&3].&1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Milo, Thanks for your help. but i dont want to hard code building or Campus(it could be anything), i want value of level field (whatever it is) will be the key and value of that key is the value of name field. please suggest if there is any solution.

Comment: Hi Milo, one more help please : if i am updating my input like { "devid" = " 1000"
"ances": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "level": "Building",
        "name": " Metro Campus Outdoor"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "level": "Campus",
        "name": " Metro Campus"
    }
]

Comment: Hi Milo, one more help please : if i am updating my input like { "devid" = " 1000"
"ances": [
    {   "id": 1,
        "level": "Building",
        "name": " Metro Campus Outdoor"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "level": "Campus",
        "name": " Metro Campus"
    }]     in spec when i am adding "devid": "result.devid" before "ances" it is just pinting devid only but my expected output  {  "result":{ 
 "devid":"1000" [
 { "Building_id": 1,
      "Building": "my building for Outdoor"
    },
    {      "Building_id": 2,
      "Campus": "Man Metro Campus"
    }
  ]}
}

Comment: i have json {
  "deveui": "1000000000000000",
  "vars": [
    {
      "nvoCfgNo": "255"
    },
    {
      "nvoLampStatus": {
        "lampStatus": "unknown(0xff)",
        "lampLevel": "255"
      }
    },
    { "nvoVolt": "255" },
    {"gps": {"lat": "12.934638","lon": "77.693950" } },
    {"status": "up"},
    {"last_status_change": 1503452208 }
  ]
}